# Ruby on Rails internal API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of general questions which I can't find the answer online regarding `internal api`.

I understand how an external API works, for example, if I have an endpoint in my application, then an external source can make an API call to that endpoint e.g. `GET`, and JSON is returned.

However I don't understand the difference between if I were to call the same endpoint within my own application (through a button click which would just be a regular get request). Is this considered an `internal` API call, or is it just a regular request and it changes to `external` based on the context?

Is the returned value the only difference? e.g. external API is JSON, and internal would return code back to a view page?

Comment: The response format depends on the `Content-Type` of the request. If you want more insight you can search for how `respond_to` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a button/link it usually sends an html request, which is defined by `Accept` header:

```rb
def show
  puts request.headers["Accept"]
  # => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"
  #     ^^^^^^^^^
  #     it's an html request. it's up to you (and rails) to respond with html
  #     or ignore it and render something else.
end
```

By default, *Rails* will render `show.html.erb` template and set `Content-Type` header to `text/html`.

Then you add `show.json.jbuilder`. Now you can ask for a *json* response instead of an *html*:

```js
// with javascript
fetch("/models/1" , { headers: { Accept: "application/json" } })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json)) // do something with the response

// and in controller you can see
// request.headers["Accept"] # => "application/json"
```

It's a *json* request so rails will render a *json* template.

*Rails* also gives you a way to render a particular response without using headers. Just add `.json` to the url. `Accept: text/html` in this case is ignored by rails and it will render a json template.

I don't remember any internal/external api concepts in rails, just a request and response.

If you need to add more logic in the controller to handle different types of requests use `respond_to` method:

```rb
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :different_template }
    format.json { render json: {error: "i'm not an api."} }
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the Rails Guides, the `internal API` consists mainly of `private` methods, although there is a way to make otherwise `public` methods `internal`. This is intended to be temporary, however:

> When writing documentation for Rails, it's important to understand the
> difference between public user-facing API vs internal API.
>
> Rails, like most libraries, uses the private keyword from Ruby for
> defining internal API. However, public API follows a slightly
> different convention. Instead of assuming all public methods are
> designed for user consumption, Rails uses the :nodoc: directive to
> annotate these kinds of methods as internal API.

I recommend consulting the [Method Visibility section of the API Documentation Guidelines](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_documentation_guidelines.html#method-visibility) for further clarification and an example.