# data-turbo-stream="false" do not working for form with method POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I'm trying to perform a POST request through a form, but i don't want to a turbo_stream request be performed;  I want to perform an HTML request.

I tried put data-turbo-stream="false" in the form tag, but it keep executing a turbo-stream request.

```
<%= form_with(model: book, data: {turbo_stream: false}) do |form| %>
```

This is the generated HTML:

```
<form data-turbo-stream="false" action="/books" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="t1PouR2NA4bSleg8OBSRQhvAP1DTSmCkchiTf4aqUIWuPJjG9pJk3J58Z25o9-S2ZXhqFwaUSTfWFn0LvQZF3Q" autocomplete="off">
```

**Ruby version:** ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

**Rails version:** Rails 7.0.8

Thanks!!

This is my create method.  Always it's responding in TRUBO_STREAM format:

```
# POST /books or /books.json
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    respond_to do |format|

      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to book_url(@book), notice: "Book was successfully created." }
        format.turbo_stream
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `data-turbo="false"` to your form to disable turbo and make your form to be a regular *HTML* form:

```rb
<%= form_with(model: book, data: {turbo: false}) do |form| %>
```

> `data-turbo-stream` allows Turbo Streams to be used with *GET* requests...

> `data-turbo="false"` disables Turbo Drive on links and forms...

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/attributes*

---

**Update**

If you have both formats in your action, `turbo_stream` takes priority, but there are multiple ways to override this, for example setting `format` in your `params`:

```rb
<%= form_with model: book do |form| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :html %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

For more details:

*https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657122/207090*

Comment: data-turbo="false" avoid to Ajax request be raised;  that is not what I want.  I want request keep being through Ajax, but that it responds HTML instead of Turbo_Stream.

Comment: For example, GET requests are performed through Ajax, but response is HTML, instead of TurboStream.

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. i don't quite follow, you can  just respond with HTML, turbo can handle both responses `format.turbo_stream` or `format.html`

Comment: Yes, @Alex, but if I put data-turbo="false", the whole page is recharged in the response.  I want it behaves like a GET request in the sense that the request is made through Ajax and the reponse, although is HTML, the page is not refreshed In its whole, that is to say Turbo Drive keep working.  I don't know if I was clear..

Comment: Ok.  The idea is to deal both reponses type in the same method, since I have views that have to respond with HTML and others one with TURBO_STREAM, pointing the same method of the controller

Comment: I put my create method in the original question.

Comment: @JohanDonadoB. i got it now. I've updated my answer

Comment: Excellent!  That is just what I was needing.  Thank you, very much!